# why is this if statement with multiple conditions unreachable?

Tags: javascript

In this function, I am actually trying to modify the array but I'm logging to the console for a test.

When I write multiple conditions in an if statement with AND it becomes unreachable.

```js
arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];
filterRangeInPlace = (arr, a, b) => {
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item <= a) {
      console.log(index);
    }
  });
}
filterRangeInPlace(arr, 3, 8); //outputs index 1 and 3.
//for cond (item >= b) if I get index 2
//why doesn't this work?
arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];
filterRangeInPlace = (arr, a, b) => {
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item <= a && item >= b) {
      console.log(index);
    }
  });
}
filterRangeInPlace(arr, 3, 8);
```

Comment: A number cannot be at the same time smaller than 3 and greater than 8.

Comment: Do you know any number that is smaller than `3` and larger than `8`?

Comment: Do you mean `item <= 8 && item >=3`? or do you mean `item <= 3 || item >= 8`? No real number is both less than or equal to 8 **AND** greater or equal to 3. I'm not sure where you would get a two if there is no 2 in the array.

Comment: @n00B Basically, you need to review what `&&` means in JavaScript (and most other programming languages).

Comment: I kind of want the two values, not just one or the other, item >= 8 gives me 8, and item <= 3, gives 1 and 3. I want to put the if statement in a way that it returns 1, 3 and 8.

Comment: @Yousername index 2, which is the second to the last value.

Answer (score 1):

You say *'it is also greater than or equals to 8'* and the fact that you're expecting index 1, 2 and 3. Thus, you seem to be looking for all values smaller or equal to 3 and larger or equal to 8.

However, you're using the `&&` operator in your if statement. This equals to if **BOTH** conditions are true, then...

You are looking for the `||` operator which says, do something if **EITHER** condition a or condition b.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the OR operator would only evaluate the first truthy condition, and ignore the other one.